# My open() command is not creating a new file

Tags: c, file

I am supposed to write a program that creates new files using the `open()` command, which, everything I read says that it's supposed to do if a file doesn't already exist.

My code is like this:

```
char startroom[] = "laruee.rooms/startroom.txt";
//...
int file_descriptor;
//...
file_descriptor = open(startroom, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT );
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", startroom);
    perror("in main");
    exit(1);
}
```

However, despite everything I've googled about this command indicating that the file should get created if it doesn't already exist, the file is not getting created. (And also from everything I googled, it appears that I am the only programmer in the universe having this problem.)

What gives?

Comment: You don't have any condition there to check if it failed. It'd always print the error and exit. You want something like `if ( file_descriptor == -1) { ..}` around that error checking part.

Comment: You might improve your question by editing it to give more details.

Comment: @BlueMoon: I just retracted my downvote and close vote. The error checking happens *after* the `open` command -- it ought to succeed, as far as I can tell, and so the file **should still get created**. (But I agree that right after that nothing else happens.)

Comment: Well, `fprintf` might fail and overwrite `errno` (for the `perror`) but that is unlikely

Comment: Please improve your question. If your program is multithreaded tell us.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could be [operating-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (and even [file-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)) specific. I guess you are running on [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) on some usual file-system like [Ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) or [BTRFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs).

Read [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) & [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html). There are several reasons why an `open` could fail (and we cannot guess which is relevant for your computer).

<sup>It might happen that your code is not running in the conditions you want it to (working directory, user id...)</sup>

Then, improve your code as:

```
char startroom[] = "laruee.rooms/startroom.txt";
//...
int file_descriptor = open(startroom, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT );
if (file_descriptor < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s : %s\n", 
            startroom, strerror(errno));
    char wdbuf[256];
    if (getcwd(wdbuf, sizeof(wdbuf))
      fprintf(stderr, "in %s\n", wdbuf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

When using `perror` or `strerror` on `errno`  you don't want any function which might change `errno` to be called after the failing syscall. On Linux with [glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) the [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) function knows about `%m` ....

BTW, you could also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) your program

Perhaps look also in your `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`. Be sure your disk is not full (use `df -h` and `df -i`). If you have [disk quotas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota), be sure to not overflow them. Be sure that your program is running in the directory you want it to and that current directory contains a `laruee.rooms/` sub-directory; you might get it with [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) like I did above.

Particularly for server-like programs, you might want to use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html).

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

BTW your `open` is not a *command* (that would be [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html)) but a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) or at least a [POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)